# XML:JAXB Mapping Java Objects and XML Document

Tags: java, android, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to implement all Java classes for handling the following XML code snippet:

```
<party date="2012-09-30"> 
    <guest name="Albert"> 
      <drink>wine</drink> 
    </guest>
</party>
```

I've wrote 3 classes:

Party.java:

```
package li.mnet.www.java.xml;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "party")

public class Party {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "date")
    private String partyDate;

   public Party() {}

    public String getPartyDate() {return partyDate;}

    public void setPartyDate(String partyDate) {
       this.partyDate = partyDate;
    }
}
```

Guest.java:

```
package li.mnet.www.java.xml;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Guests {
    private String name;

    public Guests() {}

    public void setGuestName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getGuestName() {return name;}

}
```

PartyRunner.java:

```
package li.mnet.www.java.xml;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class PartyRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Party party = new Party();
        Guests guest = new Guests();

        party.setPartyDate("2012-09-03");
        guest.setGuestName("Albert");

        JAXBContext context;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Party.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(party, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

After running the application i get following console output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<party date="2012-09-03"/>
```

What do i have to change, that class Guest.java gets printed out too?

Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're trying to marshal some data through JAXB, you'll give it an instance of your class (here is Party) and it will traverse your object and all of its attributes and tries to serialize them to the final output using hints provided by JAXB annotations.

Remember that JAXB ignores properties of the class which has no JAXB annotation. Also You can it tell whether to generate an `XML Element` or `XML Attribute` for given class property. You can use these annotations on properties or their `getter` methods.

In your example, you want to have a `guest` element inside `party` element. In your `main` method (in `PartyRunner`), you're marshaling an instance of `Party` class, but this class has no reference to your `Guests` class. Creating an instance of `Guests` class wouldn't be enough. You have to create a logical relationship between two classes and annotate them to make it possible to generate an appropriate XML. So your `Party` class should be something like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "party")

public class Party {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "date")
    private String partyDate;

    @XmlElement(name="guest")
    private Guests guests;

    public Party() {}

    public String getPartyDate() {return partyDate;}

    public void setPartyDate(String partyDate) {
        this.partyDate = partyDate;
    }

    public Guests getGuests() {
        return guests;
    }

    public void setGuests(Guests guests) {
        this.guests = guests;
    }
}
```

If you run the `PartyRunner` again you'll have something like this in your output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<party>
    <partyDate>2012-09-03</partyDate>
    <guest>
        <name>Albert</name>
    </guest>
</party>
```

As you can see, there is an inner element named `name` in your `guests` element. This is due to the annotation you've specified for `getGuestName` method in your `Guests` class. In order to make JAXB to generate an XML attribute for this property (instead of an XML element), you need to change the JAXB annotation in your `Guests` class too. You have annotated the `getGuestName` method as `@XmlElement`. This will cause to generate an XML element. If you change it to `@XmlAttribute` and run the `PartyRunner` again, you'll have this in your output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<party date="2012-09-03">
    <guest name="Albert"/>
</party>
```

Also in your sample XML you have a `drink` element inside your `guests` property. Same is true for `drink` property. The `drink` could be a `String` property in your `Guests` class annotated as `@XmlAttribute(name = "drink")`. So your final `Guests` class to generate the XML mentioned at the beginning of your question should be something like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Guests {
    private String name;
    private String drinkType;

    public Guests(){}

    public void setGuestName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String getGuestName() {return name;}

    @XmlElement(name = "drink")
    public String getDrinkType() {
        return drinkType;
    }

    public void setDrinkType(String drinkType) {
        this.drinkType = drinkType;
    }
}
```

and your `PartyRunner` should initialize the `drink` property to something like `wine`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Party party = new Party();
    Guests guest = new Guests();

    party.setPartyDate("2012-09-03");
    guest.setGuestName("Albert");
    guest.setDrinkType("wine");
    party.setGuests(guest);

    JAXBContext context;
    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Party.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(party, System.out);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the party class should contain a guest (or list of guests if you want more)

```
public class Party {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "date")
    private String partyDate;
    private Guest guest;

    public Party() {}

    public String getPartyDate() {return partyDate;}

    public void setPartyDate(String partyDate) {
       this.partyDate = partyDate;
    }
    // getter and setter for guest
}
```

set the guest of the party object then marshal the party object.

Also change the XmlElement annotiantion to XmlAttribute in the guest class at the name.